# Alternative to groupBy on several columns in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by

I have a spark data frame with columns like so:

```
df
--------------------------
A     B     C    D    E    F   amt
"A1"  "B1" "C1" "D1" "E1"  "F1"  1
"A2"  "B2" "C2" "D2" "E2"  "F2"  2
```

I would like to perform groupBy with column combinations

```
(A, B, sum(amt))
(A, C, sum(amt))
(A, D, sum(amt))
(A, E, sum(amt))
(A, F, sum(amt))
```

such that the resulting data frame looks like:

```
df_grouped
----------------------
A     field    value   amt
"A1"    "B"     "B1"    1
"A2"    "B"     "B2"    2
"A1"    "C"     "C1"    1
"A2"    "C"     "C2"    2
"A1"    "D"     "D1"    1
"A2"    "D"     "D2"    2
```

My attempt at this was the following:

```
val cols = Vector("B","C","D","E","F")
//code for creating empty data frame with structs for the cols A, field, value and act
for (col <- cols){
   empty_df = empty_df.union (df.groupBy($"A",col)
  .agg(sum(amt).as(amt)
  .withColumn("field",lit(col)
  .withColumnRenamed(col, "value"))
}
```

I feel that the usage "for" or "foreach" may be clumsy for a distributed env such as spark. Are there any alternatives with map functionality for what I am doing? In my mind, aggregateByKey and collect_list may work; however, I am unable to imagine a complete solution. Please advise.

Comment: Are you just looking to unpivot the values of `B,C,D,E,F`? What role is `sum(amt)` playing?

Comment: My original dataframe is a large set. I have condensed it down to a few rows for making it simple and understandable. Since it is large, I thought for loop may not be the best approach in terms of memory usage, so foldleft may be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`foldLeft` is very powerful function devised in Scala** if you *know how to play with it*. I am suggesting you to *use `foldLeft` function* ( I have *commented for clarity in the code and for explanation*)

```
//selecting the columns without A and amt
val columnsForAggregation = df.columns.tail.toSet - "amt"

//creating an empty dataframe (format for final output
val finalDF = Seq(("empty", "empty", "empty", 0.0)).toDF("A", "field", "value", "amt")

//using foldLeft for the aggregation and merging each aggreted results
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val (originaldf, transformeddf) = columnsForAggregation.foldLeft((df, finalDF)){(tempdf, column) => {
  //aggregation on the dataframe with A and one of the column and finally selecting as required in the outptu
  val aggregatedf = tempdf._1.groupBy("A", column).agg(sum("amt").as("amt"))
    .select(col("A"), lit(column).as("field"), col(column).as("value"), col("amt"))
  //union the aggregated results and transferring dataframes for next loop
  (df, tempdf._2.union(aggregatedf))
}
}

//finally removing the dummy row created
transformeddf.filter(col("A") =!= "empty")
  .show(false)
```

You should have the dataframe you desire

```
+---+-----+-----+---+
|A  |field|value|amt|
+---+-----+-----+---+
|A1 |E    |E1   |1.0|
|A2 |E    |E2   |2.0|
|A1 |F    |F1   |1.0|
|A2 |F    |F2   |2.0|
|A2 |B    |B2   |2.0|
|A1 |B    |B1   |1.0|
|A2 |C    |C2   |2.0|
|A1 |C    |C1   |1.0|
|A1 |D    |D1   |1.0|
|A2 |D    |D2   |2.0|
+---+-----+-----+---+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Concised form of above `foldLeft` function** is

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val (originaldf, transformeddf) = columnsForAggregation.foldLeft((df, finalDF)){(tempdf, column) => 
  (df, tempdf._2.union(tempdf._1.groupBy("A", column).agg(sum("amt").as("amt")).select(col("A"), lit(column).as("field"), col(column).as("value"), col("amt"))))
}
```

Comment: This is more elegant. Thank you. Is foldleft method better in terms of memory usage as well?

Comment: yes I gess so .If it helped you consider accepting and upvoting :)

Comment: My original dataframe is a large set. I have condensed it down to a few rows for making it simple and understandable. Since it is large, I thought for loop may not be the best approach in terms of memory usage, so foldleft may be better.

Comment: go for it . Test it and observe ;)